# Transform scale Image using window scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

My opacity style is fired when scrolling down the page, however my transform scale is not. Any thoughts on how to solve this one or what I am missing?

**Codepen:**
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wyrBLE

Html:

```
<div class="top"><div class="title">Fade out</div></div>
```

Scss:

```
.top {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'helvetica';
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #fff;
  background: url("http://via.placeholder.com/350x150");
  background-position:center;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 100px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  $(".top").css({
  'opacity' : 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / 250,
  'transform': 'scale(1.5)' - $(window).scrollTop() / 250
  });
});
```

Comment: because of invalid value `transform:scale(1.5) - 10(or any value)`

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to add a string to an integer, try this :-

```
'transform': 'scale(' + (1.5 - $(window).scrollTop() / 250) + ')'
```